# How to use a start_el variable in start_lvl

Tags: menus, walker

On top of the sub-menu list items i would like to insert a `<h2>parent-description</h2>` line which i expect to show the description (or the title if wanted) of the parent item. 
Such as;

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a href="">German Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">BMW</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Mercedes</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Volkswagen</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="">American Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">Chrysler</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Ford</a></li>
         <li><a href="">General Motors</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

should look like

```
<ul>
   <li> <!-- $item->description of this list item has to be passed to start_lvl -->
      <a href="">German Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <h2>Cars Made in Germany </h2> <!--parent list item's description shows here-->
         <li><a href="">BMW</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Mercedes</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Volkswagen</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="">American Cars</a>
      <ul>
         <h2>Cars Made in the USA</h2> <!--parent list item's description shows here-->
         <li><a href="">Chrysler</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Ford</a></li>
         <li><a href="">General Motors</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

What i know;

- I have basic knowledge on how to modify the walker by extending to walker_nav_menu.
- I know that to insert the `<h2>parent-description</h2>` after the `<ul>` and before the `<li>`s i have to concatenate the $output var of the start_lvl method.
- I know that the $item->description value is avalable within the start_el method.

What i don't know is, how to pass the $item->description value of start_el method (which is used one previously) to the start_lvl method at the time it produces the `<ul>` tag for  list items to follow.

From some previous questions and answers here I implemented something like this but it didn't work.

```
class My_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
   private $curItem;

  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
     $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' );
     $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul>' . '<h2>' . $this->curItem->description . '</h2> . "\n";
  }

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
     $this-> curItem = $item;
     $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' );
     $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<li"' . list item thingys here . '">' . "\n";
  }
}
```

Any helps highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, Redu - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Couple quick notes: your desired markup is invalid - all direct descendants of a `<ul>` must be `<li>`s in order to conform to the HTML spec. Your description `<h2>`s should either be moved up a level and placed under the `<a>` they describe, or placed within their own `<li>` in the sub-`<ul>`. Are you certain the code you've posted is as-written on your WP installation? The second line of `start_lvl()` is missing a single quote. To use the object operator `->`, no whitespace should be present on either side, ie `$object->property`

Comment: PHP should have thrown errors for the syntax errors in the posted code - [make sure `WP_DEBUG` is enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) in your `wp-config.php` such that you're not missing out on any useful errors or warnings.